Keyboard toolbar item causing screen jump
I'm working on an iOS app in SwiftUI and I am having an issue when dismissing a keyboard from a button in the keyboard toolbar. The toolbar itself is not going away with the keyboard. Instead it is going to the bottom of the view and then disappearing causing the screen to jump down to fill the space. The video is from a simulator but the same issue is happening on my actual device as well.
video example
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Form{
            titleField
            balance
            FillType
            category
        
            Section(content: {
                
            }, footer: {
                createButton
            })
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal){
                Text("Create Bucket").font(.headline)
            }
            ToolbarItem{
                Button("Cancel"){
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }.fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard){
                Spacer()
                Button("Done") {
                    focused = nil
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
        .sheet(isPresented: $openCategory, content: {
            CategoryPicker(category: $selectedCategory)
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(2/3)])
                .presentationCornerRadius(20)
        })
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
}

